# file not found when using jquery and http handler using FireFox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ihttphandler

The code below is used to copy a file into a directory but I continue to get an exception "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\abc.jpg" file not found error.  Thanks for any assistance or ideas.  I'm using VS2010, jQuery 1.8.1 (min), IIS 7 on a Windows 7 machine.  I do have FileUpload.ashx in both  and  elements in my webconfig.

**This issue only occurs using FireFox.**

HTML Markup

```
    var FileName = null;     

$.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "FileUpload.ashx",
            data: { FileName: FileName },
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });

   function setFileName(e) {
        FileName = e.value;         
    }
```

Code behind for FileUpload

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        try
        {

            String FileID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


            String sDirectory = "~/UploadedFiles/";
            String sFileName = context.Request["FileName"];
            String sUploadPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}", sDirectory, sFileName);
            sUploadPath = context.Server.MapPath(sUploadPath);


            string FileName = context.Request["FileName"];
            FileInfo fn = new FileInfo(FileName);

            fn.CopyTo(sUploadPath + FileID + "_" + fn.Name);

     }

     catch (Exception ex)
         {
    string message = ex.Message;
         }

      }
```

Comment: Your AJAX call is just sending a filename, not the file itself.

Comment: thank you Barmar.  I'm using the FileUpload control from asp.net and getting the file uploaded.  Yes, you are right the only thing being sent up from FF is the file name.  However, in IE I notice that the path and file name is being passed up.